# The codec can't decode bytes in Python

Tags: python, unicode

This is my code, but the result is not what I want,

```
def read_message():

   quotes = open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\movie_quotes.txt")
   read_file = quotes.read()
   print(read_file)
   quotes.close()

read_message()
```

The result shows that:

```
File "E:/Python/p1/send_message.py", line 4
quotes = open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\movie_quotes.txt")
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

And I do not understand the exact meaning. 
My python version is 3.5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a raw string, double your slashes or use forward slashes instead:

`r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\movie_quotes.txt'
'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\movie_quotes.txt'
'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt'`

Comment: None of these works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `SyntaxError`. That means the error is in your source code itself, not something that happens during its execution.

In your code, "`\U`" in "`\Users`" is interpreted as a start of a [long Unicode literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=literals#index-15). Double the backslashes or use a raw string literal to fix that as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double slashes, like so :

```
quotes = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\movie_quotes.txt"),
```

OR forward slashes:

```
quotes = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt")
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause a "unicode error".

Comment: It would most certainly.